# How do I use Kate's text filter plugin for macros?

Tags: editor, kate

I've been through just about every editor on Linux (gedit, geany, vim, gvim), and decided that **kate** works best for me.

However, it doesn't easily support macros, and I need to do a search and replace.  So I am trying to use kate's Text Filter plugin, and sed.

I want to remove double quotes from a SQL statement that I pasted from a Java module, so that I can run it.

I tried entering this in the text filter with the entire block of text selected, but it just told me **/bin/sed: no input files**.

I know I can do a search and replace, but I may want to expand this to do other things to the file.

Does someone know how to use this plugin?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Its just a tiny little thing:

Don't use the `-i` option.

Your command should look like this:

```
sed 's/"//g'
```